# Extract vowels of each string value and make separate 3x3 array using Python

Tags: python

Extract vowels of each string value and make a separate 3,3 array consisting of vowels of the respective string value.
Example:

`array=[["me","i" , "my"],["we", "us", "ours"],["you", "yours", "them"]]`

> output=[['e', 'i', None], ['e', 'u', 'ou'], ['ou', 'ou', 'e']]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
matrix = [["me", "i", "my"],["we", "us", "ours"],["you", "yours", "them"]]

def ex_vowels(word):
    vowels = [c for c in word if c.lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')]
    return "".join(vowels) if vowels else None

vowel_matrix = [[ex_vowels(word) for word in sub] for sub in matrix]
print(vowel_matrix)
```

This prints:

```
[['e', 'i', None], ['e', 'u', 'ou'], ['ou', 'ou', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
def checkVowel(arr):
  st=""
  for i in arr:
    if i in ['a','A','e','E','i','I','o',"O",'u',"U"]:
      st+=i
  return st


def myFunction(matrix):
  row_lenth=len(matrix)
  col_lenth=len(matrix[0])
  temp_arr=[[None for i in range(col_lenth)]for j in range(row_lenth)]
  for i in range(row_lenth):
    for j in range(col_lenth):
      ans=checkVowel(matrix[i][j])
      if len(ans)>0:
        temp_arr[i][j]=ans
  print(temp_arr)


a=[["me","i" , "my"],["we", "us", "ours"],["you", "yours", "them"]]
myFunction(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.
Both solutions are working perfectly fine.
I would prefer the first one since my code was somewhat similar to the first one.

Comment: @ParamveerYadav no problem at least give an upvote.